# How do I answer y automatically (kill-matching-buffers asks if I should kill a modified buffer)?

Tags: emacs, buffer

In Emacs - how do I kill buffers matching regexp?

**Edit**:

How do I answer `y` automatically (`kill-matching-buffers` asks if I should kill a modified buffer)?

Something like this?

```
(defun bk-kill-buffers (bfrRgxp)
  (interactive)
  (kill-matching-buffers bfrRgxp)
  [return])
```

Comment: Why using SO when google is enough?

Comment: I didn't expect built-in solution.

Comment: @LucaMartini: now with the Edit it is less trivial.

Comment: @phils: isn't it perfectly readable, while very short? I heard the first edition of bible were without vowels at all.

Comment: I suppose it might be readable to people who write like that on their cellphones. I knew what the question was, but literally stared at that wondering why you had used a random collection of letters for an argument name.

Comment: Do you have to use `kill-matching-buffers` at all? (It's a lousy command, IMHO.) Rather than fiddle with `cl-letf`, `flet`, or any such wrapper, just write your own command that does what `kill-matching-buffer` does, but use `kill-buffer` instead of `kill-buffer-ask`. The code is trivial; if you want, just copy the code from `kill-matching-buffers` and substitute `kill-buffer`.

Comment: See also [my reply in the emacs-devel@gnu.org thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2017-05/msg00644.html).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How do I answer y automatically (kill-matching-buffers asks if I should kill a modified buffer)?

`kill-matching-buffers` calls `kill-buffer-ask` which calls `yes-or-no-p`. You could temporarily redefine the latter, but for safety reasons I am inclined not to do that -- killing a given buffer could trigger other functionality which needs to ask a yes-or-no question.

Redefining `kill-buffer-ask` seems a safer bet (or simply copying and modifying the `kill-matching-buffers` function itself).

```el
(require 'cl)
(defun bk-kill-buffers (regexp)
  "Kill buffers matching REGEXP without asking for confirmation."
  (interactive "sKill buffers matching this regular expression: ")
  (flet ((kill-buffer-ask (buffer) (kill-buffer buffer)))
    (kill-matching-buffers regexp)))
```

Comment: Emacs 24.3: "'flet' is an obsolete macro (as of 24.3); use either 'cl-flet' or 'cl-letf'." Switching to either one of these (without other mods) doesn't work correctly. `cl-flet` still asks and `cl-letf` produces a run-time error: "bk-kill-buffers: 'let' bindings can have only one value-form: kill-buffer-ask, (buffer), (kill-buffer buffer)"

Comment: But in spite of the deprecation warning, `flet` still works.

Comment: Neither of the suggested alternatives are identical to `flet`, but `cl-letf` *can* be used in this instance, like so:  `(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'kill-buffer-ask) #'kill-buffer)) ...)`

Comment: This gives this error when I try to save a file afterwards: `Symbol’s function definition is void: tuareg-mode
`

Comment: @alper That's nothing to do with this code.  Use `toggle-debug-on-error` to learn more.

Comment: But instead if I use `cl-letf` error does not occur => `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function tuareg-mode)
  tuareg-mode()
  kill-buffer(#<buffer empty_file.txt>)
  server-delete-client(#<process server <1>>)
  server-save-buffers-kill-terminal(nil)
  save-buffers-kill-terminal(nil)
  funcall-interactively(save-buffers-kill-terminal nil)
  call-interactively(save-buffers-kill-terminal nil nil)
  command-execute(save-buffers-kill-terminal)
`

Comment: @alper For some reason killing your `empty_file.txt` buffer has resulted in an attempted call to some undefined `tuareg-mode` function. I would be looking at `C-h v kill-buffer-query-functions` and `C-h v kill-buffer-hook` in that buffer. Again, very much nothing to do with the code here.

Comment: @alper If you can provide a recipe starting from `emacs -Q` to reproduce the issue, please do; otherwise I can only assure you that your issue is caused by something else.

Comment: How can I run your function when starting with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @alper https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/evaluating-elisp-emacs

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kill-matching-buffers`. Below code effectively behaves as if `kill-buffer` (which does not ask before killing) was called instead of `kill-buffer-ask`:

```el
(defun kill-matching-buffers-just-do-it ()
  "Kill buffers whose names match REGEXP, without asking."
  (interactive)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'kill-buffer-ask) #'kill-buffer))
    (call-interactively #'kill-matching-buffers)))
```

Comment: I believe this should be: 
    ```(defun kill-matching-buffers-no-ask (regexp)
      "Kill buffers whose names match REGEXP, without asking."
      (interactive)
      (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'kill-buffer-ask) #'kill-buffer))
        (kill-matching-buffers regexp)))```

Comment: @JustinSchell Why do you think so? I just reviewed my snippet again and even tried it. It works. If you want to add `regexp` arg to `kill-matching-buffers-no-ask`, you will need to make the `interactive` form accept string arg (`"s"` type) too. Instead it's just easy to let `kill-matching-buffers` do that .. and thus the `call-interactively`.

Comment: Sorry, I was slightly confused because I was trying to use your function with a hydra :post configuration where I wanted to use a specific buffer name as the function argument and I was encountering an error.  For the hydra, I should have just been using a non-interactive function like `(defun kill-matching-buffers-no-ask (regexp)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'kill-buffer-ask) #'kill-buffer))
    (kill-matching-buffers regexp)))`

Answer (score 1):

For Emacs version >=24, the **kmb.el** library from ELPA repository
does exactly that with the command `kmb-kill-matching-buffers-no-ask`.

It also provides the command `kmb-delete-process-and-kill-buffer-no-ask`,
which kills the current buffer (without confirmation).

I bind the latter command as follows:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "H-M-<delete>") 'kmb-delete-process-and-kill-buffer-no-ask)
```

so that i don't call it accidentaly, just when i need it.

Comment: This function is works also as it's expected in the question. by using `(kmb-delete-process-and-kill-buffer-no-ask bfrRgxp)`, you can kill buffers without yes-no question.

Answer (score -1):

```
M-x kill-matching-buffers
```

This will prompt for a regex, check the documentation for details.

Comment: The OP already knows that function. They need to know how to skip the yes/no prompt after calling that fn.